# How can read CSV, delimiters, separators error

Tags: pandas, csv

The first I was type:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("oktober.csv", header = None, skiprows=2, engine='python')
df
```

**Than pd was the table with separators ';'**

0
Pattern changed :;24.10.2019 12:18:47;Target :...

1
Pattern number : 1 ;B3377;Description :;;Alloy...

2
Weight net: ;0;Weight gross: ;180

3
Flask no.;moulded;State;poured;State;Emptied;T...

4
18222;04.11.2019 09:29:20;0;;0;08.11.2019 15:3...
...

...

4909
22319;26.11.2019 10:04:09;0;;0;;450;646;0;0;;

4910
22320;26.11.2019 10:04:54;0;;0;;450;449;0;0;;

4911
; ; ;min; ;450;584; ; ; ; ;

4912
; ; ;max; ;450;3781; ; ; ; ;

4913
; ; ;avg; ;450;1443; ; ; ; ;

220
18395;08.11.2019 15:34:46;0;08.11.2019 16:12:4...

221
18396;08.11.2019 15:35:37;0;08.11.2019 16:13:0...

222
18397;08.11.2019 15:36:25;0;08.11.2019 16:13:3...

223
; ; ;min; ;450;461; ; ; ; ;

224
; ; ;max; ;450;8223; ; ; ; ;

225
; ; ;avg; ;450;1185; ; ; ; ;

226
Pattern changed :;08.11.2019 15:37:15;Target :...

227
Pattern number : 1 ;B2238;Description :;;Alloy...

228
Weight net: ;0;Weight gross: ;

229
Flask no.;moulded;State;poured;State;Emptied;T...

230
18398;08.11.2019 15:38:35;0;08.11.2019 16:14:3...

When I was try with separators and delimiters I got the error :Expected 7 fields in line 227, saw 11

```
import pandas as pd
  df=pd.read_csv("oktober.csv", header = None, skiprows=2, engine='python',sep=';'  )
   df
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To debug this, it is nice to see what exactly is on line 227. Because there it sees more columns than it needs to

Comment: I  added more columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have your input data in some disorder, at least if
the number of semicolons in each row is concerned.

*read_csv* is known to poorly cope with such cases, so take a two-step
approach:

1. Read the source file with no *sep=';'* parameter, reading the whole line
   into a **single** column (I called it *src*):

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', skiprows=2, header=None, names=['src'])
   ```
2. Then "expand" each line into a sequence of fields, preferably in another DataFrame:

   ```
   df2 = df.src.apply(lambda txt: pd.Series(txt.split(';'))).replace(np.nan, '')
   ```

To avoid *NaN* in the result (obstructing the visibility), I replaced them with
empty strings.

For a couple of rows from your sample I got:

```
                       0                    1               2       3      4                5  6
0    0 Pattern changed :  24.10.2019 12:18:47        Target :                                    
1  1 Pattern number : 1                 B3377   Description :          Alloy                     
2         2 Weight net:                     0  Weight gross:      180                            
3            3 Flask no.              moulded           State  poured  State          Emptied  T 
4                4 18222  04.11.2019 09:29:20               0              0  08.11.2019 15:3
```

Maybe this result will be a source material to tidy up your source file,
e.g. identify row with disorder, add missing semicolons and then read again
(your choice).

Consider also setting column names to a meaningful set of strings.

Comment: The name of faile is src, this is the name of my file that i will read? The file must be txt?And what is the name io? maybe I must at start type some special imort as txt or something like this? Maybe are those stupid questions but I am new here :) Thank you.

Comment: Initially I wrote the first argument of *pd.read_csv* as *io.StringIO(txt)*
because actually I read from a string variable (*txt*).
But in "real world" you should read from a file, so now I put *input.csv* there.
The name of a column (*src*) I assumed arbitrarily (any name is OK).